# JMeter authorization configuration using a static API token key

Tags: api, jmeter, token, jira

We are using JMeter v5.3 to run performance tests against our SIT Server instance of JIRA v8.13.22. We setup our JMeter tests with basic authentication via the "HTTP Authorization Manager" and the "Basic Digest" mechanism. We have recently installed the "API Token Authentication for Jira" plugin and turned off basic authentication to JIRA. See: [Plugin Admin docs](https://wiki.resolution.de/doc/api-token-authentication/latest/admin-guide). Therefore all REST calls to JIRA via application accounts must now login with an application user that has a registered API key with JIRA.

As expected, our JMeter tests now fail with "403 Forbidden" errors due to the Basic Auth setup with the error: "Basic Auth with password is disabled by the API Token Authentication app". I found articles similar to [JMeter Authorization with access token](https://qaautomation.expert/2020/05/22/jmeter-authorization-with-access-token), but they use "authorization with **dynamic** access token".

How do we configure JMeter to authorize with a registered **static** API token key?

Comment: Yes, some of our applications simply work by swapping out the basic credentials with the API Token key but not JMeter. We commonly test JIRA via the following example curl command:
```
 curl -u "jiratester:jiratester-SIT-API-Token" "https://jirasit-api.abc.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue/WTA-1137"

```
Looks like I will need to play with creating a test plan with that curl string and plug it into my test case.

Comment: Resolved!  I generated a new Test Plan with your curl syntax, which validated without errors and inserted these components into my existing test plan.   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to read the documentation you linked yourself? Because the [very first stanza](https://wiki.resolution.de/doc/api-token-authentication/latest/user-guide/using-tokens-examples) which I see looks like:

> The Token use itself is very simple - **in the place where you would usually use the password, you just use the Token itself**

Previously you were sending [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of `Basic`  followed by your [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded credentials (this is what [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) was doing under the hood). So all you need to do is to replace the password with the token and that would be it.

You can also send the same `Authorization` header with the value of [`Bearer`](https://wiki.resolution.de/doc/api-token-authentication/latest/user-guide/using-tokens-examples#id-.UsingTokensExamplesv1.7.0-BearerAuthheader)  followed by your token value. It can be done using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)

Here is an [example](https://wiki.resolution.de/doc/api-token-authentication/latest/user-guide/using-tokens-examples#id-.UsingTokensExamplesv1.7.0-cURLExample.1) of authenticating via curl:

```
curl "https://YOUR_JIRA_BASEURL/rest/api/2/myself" \
 -u '<USERNAME>:<YOUR_API_TOKEN>'
```

And in JMeter you can generate a Test Plan from curl command

[image]